# UIAlertView insert image

Tags: ios

I am trying to add an image in a UIAlertView in this way:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Accept Connection?"
                          message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ wants to connect with you", newStr]
                          delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                          otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 100, 50)];
NSString *imgPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"BluetoothDeviceiPhone.png"]];
UIImage *yourImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imgPath];
[imageView setImage:yourImage];
[alertView addSubview:imageView];
[alertView show];
alertView.tag = 2;
```

The image is not showing though, neither a space is showing, just the text. Why??

Comment: UIAlertView does not support adding any subviews in iOS 7

Comment: I get it: There is officially no addSubview nor subclassing for UIAlertView in iOS7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this sample code it also running in ios7 and prior

https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview